# php frameworks for simple tasks, an overkill?

Tags: php, frameworks

Example:
I need to manage users in a website,'manage' means: register and allow them to send comments.
user registration will use: `username`, `email`, `password` and `user_id`
comments will have: `date`, `link`, `text` and `user_id`

Now, I have several projects with similar structure - give or take a table/field or two..

I hate writing it all again and again, but using cakePHP/ ZEND / Symfony seems like an overkill and lots of work anyway.

Any thoughts? ideas? tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a framework. Especially if you have "several projects with similar structure". When you get sufficiently familiar with it, it will stop being a hassle to set up.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use a pre-packaged framework or a content management system, you'll probably end up with coming up with something similar yourself: a bunch of code and process you reuse to simplify and speed-up those repetitive tasks.

As to which approach is better depends on you, your development preferences, and maybe your client's perceptions (they may give the work different a value if you rely on a 3rd party system, they may even have opinions on which can be used & installed).

Comment: +1 I agree; no matter what road you take you should be rewriting about the same amount of code, because both roads should (if you setup your sites in a modular, loosely coupled, etc. manner) have some sort of generic and flexible structure, which you appropriate to the particular requirements.